# How to find music position and duration for sound 'sprites'?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, sprite, howler.js

I'm making a videogame and I have an audio file called "sounds.mp3" where all my sounds are.

I'm using [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/), and I need to know where exactly the sound is positioned, and what is its duration.

```
sound = new Howl({
    urls: ['assets/sounds.mp3'],
    volume: 0.2,
    sprite: {
        point: [0, 700],
        blast: [0, 2000], // start , duration
        laser: [3000, 700], // sound.play('laser');
        winner: [5000, 9000]
    },
    onload: function() {
        init(); // when every music or sound is loaded
    }
});
```

Here, laser sound would start at second 3, and its duration would be one 0,7 seconds.

I know there are tools for image sprites like [GetSpriteXY](https://getspritexy.netlify.com/) or [Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com/), would be awesome if someone knows a similar tool for this.

The actual code works, I just need a better way to pinpoint the sound whitin the file than just listening carefully.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for this:

1. You can load the sound into Audacity (http://www.audacityteam.org/), then simply double-click on each section of audio to select it and the bottom row will show you the info such as start and end position.
2. If you have the individual audio tracks separate from the compiled sound sprite, you might consider using something like soundsprite (https://github.com/realbluesky/soundsprite) to generate the sprite file. It is compatible with the howler.js format and will output everything you need.

Comment: I finally used Audacity. It works fine! The information displayed at the bottom was very useful as I could see the duration of the sound too. Thank you again.